# Set maximum and minimum zooming levels for image

Tags: java, android, xml, image, zooming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Imageview issue with zoom in and out,drag with maximum and minimum levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357090/imageview-issue-with-zoom-in-and-out-drag-with-maximum-and-minimum-levels)

I have image zooming and dragging in my application. My requirement is the image sets maximum and minimum zooming levels. I have used the below code.

```
public class PinchZoomListener implements OnTouchListener {

    private static final String TAG = "Touch";
    // These matrices will be used to move and zoom image
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

    // We can be in one of these 3 states
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;

    // Remember some things for zooming
    PointF start = new PointF();
    PointF mid = new PointF();
    float oldDist = 1f;

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
        dumpEvent(event);// Dump touch event to log

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
            mode = DRAG;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            oldDist = spacing(event);
            Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
            if (oldDist > 10f) {
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                midPoint(mid, event);
                mode = ZOOM;
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            mode = NONE;
            Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mode == DRAG) {
                // ...
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y);
            } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                float newDist = spacing(event);
                Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                if (newDist > 10f) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                    matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
        return true; // indicate event was handled
    }

    /** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */
    private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE", "POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int action = event.getAction();
        int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
        sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);
        if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
            sb.append("(pid ").append(action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
            sb.append(")");
        }
        sb.append("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
            sb.append("#").append(i);
            sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
            sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
            sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
            if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
                sb.append(";");
        }
        sb.append("]");
        Log.d(TAG, sb.toString());
    }

    /** Determine the space between the first two fingers */
    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    /** Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers */
    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }
}
```

How can I set maximum and minimum zooming levels for image in Android?

Comment: What does this have to do with XML?

Comment: I dint read your code. But you could just put a check inside the the listener, that if `currentZoom <= maxVal and >=minVal` then call the zoom function else exit.

Comment: NO. i am using in String thumbImageLoc = cp.getString(cp.getColumnIndex("ActImageLoc"));
   if (thumbImageLoc != null) {
    piv.setImageURI(Uri.parse(thumbImageLoc));
    piv.setOnTouchListener(new arun.apc.PinchZoomListener());
   }

Comment: @AndrewThompson, probably he used xmls somewhere in project and tagged what all technologies he used. ;-)

Comment: @veeresh, if you want to post code in comments, atleast enclose it in `backticks`.

Comment: @MukulGoel  **Every** Android project has XML files!  But I suspect you are correct.  Perhaps the OP thinks there are settings in those same files that cover min/max zoom.  ;)

Comment: @Mukul Goel i am trying your code Its not working Please help me.

Comment: Aah.. Refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656739/how-can-i-set-maximum-and-minimum-zooming-levels-for-image-in-android)

Comment: @Mukul Goel where i  call this code(float scale = Math.max(MIN_ZOOM, Math.min(scale, MAX_ZOOM));)

Answer (score 0):

You ought to rework your code, because you're using relative scales and offsets for every touch event, and there's no possible way to find out what is the absolute value of current image zoom and/or offset.

Save the absolute value of your zoom somewhere, and then you may use the before mentioned `min(max(MIN,zoom),MAX)` piece of code.